# How to pass fixture object to pytest_runtest_makereport?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, fixtures

We use the pytest library for automation test. We need to take screen shots for fail case. I want to use `mydriver` variable in `pytest_runtest_makereport` method to take screen shots with this variable for fail case. How can I do this?

Additional: We don't use the conftest.py file. Can we use the `pytest_runtest_makereport` method without conftest.py? We use just a sampleTest.py file.

sampleTest.py:

```
import time
from appium import webdriver
import pytest


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="function")
def driver():
    """Setup for the test"""
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '11.0'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Samsung Galaxy A70'
    # Since the app is already installed launching it using package and activity name
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.example.mapkitbaseline'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.example.mapkitbaseline.ui.CreationMapActivity'
    mydriver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    yield mydriver

    mydriver.quit()


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver")
def test_func1(driver):
    """"Testing the HMS MapKit demo app"""
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    time.sleep(5)

    # Assert that MapKit->.ui.CreationMapActivity->btnMapCreation4 button text is equal to "suuportfragmentx"
    elmnt = driver.find_element_by_id('com.example.mapkitbaseline:id/btnMapCreation4')
    assert elmnt.get_attribute('text').lower() == "supportmapfragmentfffffffffx"
    print(elmnt.get_attribute('text'))


@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):

    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == "call":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # I need to use mydriver variable this here. This code doesn't work.
            screenshot = mydriver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(screenshot, ''))
    # extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<style> #results-table{ position: relative;  position:absolute !important;top:300px !important; left:100px !important; width: 50% !important;  z-index: -1 !important;}</style>'))
    report.extra = extra
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access fixtures in `item.funcargs`.

```py
if 'driver' in item.fixturenames:       # Wrap in this
    mydriver = item.funcargs['driver']  # Add this
    screenshot = mydriver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image(screenshot, ''))
```

Reference: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures

---

## Use `pytest_runtest_makereport` without conftest.py

It's possible, but you probably shouldn't do it.

```py
# @pytest.mark.hookwrapper          # Replace this
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)  # with this
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # ...


import gc
import sys
from pluggy.hooks import HookImpl
from _pytest.config import Config
config = next(o for o in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(o, Config))
hookimpl = HookImpl(sys.modules[__name__], __file__, pytest_runtest_makereport, pytest_runtest_makereport.pytest_impl)
config.hook.pytest_runtest_makereport._add_hookimpl(hookimpl)
```

Comment: looks like `item.fixturenames` undocumented feat?

Comment: It's in the documentation in the linked example, but indeed not a documented feature nor always available for `Item` object based on [pytest-dev/pytest!5070](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5070).